# How to override __str__ in nested class

Tags: python, pydev, python-3.4, nested-class

I've coded a parent class and a nested class. I've already overridden the parent class `__str__` method and now I want to do the same on the nested class. But for some reason the `__str__` method in the nested class is not getting called. And I can't see the instance variables in PyDev's autocompletion list when coding inside the nested class's str. Code:

```
class Parent(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.parent_var = "Parent"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.parent_var


    class Nested(object):

        def __init__(self):
            #Works (of course, why shouldn't it?)
            self.children_var = "Child"

        def __str__(self):
            # This method never called!
            return self.children_var
```

Something odd is going on. Why can't the `__str__` method just work like the `__init__` did?

---

UPDATE:
You guys are right. The code was ok, but my **str** was trying to do this:

```
return "Some string" + some_integer
```

And apparently in Python you need to do str(some_integer) before concatenating stuff (this is actually lame).

Comment: `str(Parent.Nested())` should work fine, how are you calling it?

Comment: It's never called *by what*?! Nested classes are rarely the best approach.

Comment: What do you mean called? Try printing the instance of the Nested class.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Nested classes totally make sense. You python guys have a peculiar view of the world L)

Comment: @MisterSmith Your code is fine.

Comment: @MisterSmith fine: nested classes are rarely the best approach *in Python*. Happy to take that back if you can provide a more useful example of their use than `Parent` and `Nested`!

Comment: @MisterSmith: The most common reason to use nested classes in other languages is that those languages don't have first-class functions, or don't have functions at all, and force you to wrap them as methods of useless classes instead. Those reasons don't exist in Python. (Other uses for nested classes do make sense, they just aren't nearly as common.)

Comment: @MisterSmith: Note that Python (unlike some other languages) doesn't attach any special meaning to nested classes, see [Is it a good practice to make nested class in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30376127). Nested classes in Java are used as work-arounds for language limitations that don't exist in Python.

Comment: Day 57 and we still don't know how you actually called the `__str__` on the class. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yeah, strong typing is super lame, it should just quietly let you do the wrong thing and find out later that wasn't what you intended... Please keep the opinions out of your questions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Java is strongly typed as well and lets you do that.

Comment: Interesting, I would consider implicit coercion to be weak typing. Nonetheless, my point stands. Also, I don't see how you couldn't have diagnosed this from the `TypeError`, or why despite having nearly 10k rep you have just *edited an answer/comment into your question* (not to mention asking a question that didn't allow recreation of the issue)!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I needed the `__str__` only for debugging purposes and was not calling print directly, just using eclipse's inspector (who swallowed the error btw). So the answer/comment was actually useful. And you are right, explaining the issue deserved its own question, but I wanted to reward  @MalikBrahimi for showing me the way in a one liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print Parent.Nested() # works fine, print calls __str__ resulting in 'Child'
```

Comment: You are right. It prints ok. I was trying to concatenate strings with integers in the overriden method without calling str over the integer first. And that throwed an exception preventing eclipse from showing the correct value.

Comment: @MisterSmith Please mark as answer if this was useful.

Comment: I'm trying but it doesn't let me till 2 mins ;)

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I know you're closing on 10k, but be cool. This question is way too localised to be useful for anyone except (and possibly not even including) the OP, so should probably just be deleted.

Comment: Okay?? Thanks for the moral support.