# Is there a simpler way to pass variables from the outer class to an inner class?

Tags: python, dataframe, class

If I have the below class, is there a way to pass a variable that was defined in the outer class `__init__` constructor into the inner class constructor in the inner class?

```
class Outer:

     def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

     class Inner:
          ## Looking to pass the df into this class
```

I stumbled across [this](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-access-a-variable-from-an-outer-class-in-an-inner-nested-class-in-python) solution but I wanted to know if there was a simpler solution?

I also came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024566/how-to-access-outer-class-from-an-inner-class) solution but with this, I'd have to insert the df when calling the inner class. Is there a way to avoid this whereby if its initialised in the outer class, I can automatically retrieve it when I call the inner class or is this unavoidable?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? How are you designing your program?

Comment: There's no inherent connection between "nested classes". You may as well write them not nested, side by side, for the same effect. So no, there's no inherent way.

Comment: @BeChillerToo Trying to make a class of custom stock indicators to then store on github as a private module and then import into python. I wanted to avoid initialising of every other class in the `__init__.py` file and instead call the one outer class to have access to the others. There are quite a few.

Comment: @deceze Alright, thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an inner object until you create one, at which point you can pass any attributes of the outer class:

```
class Outer:
     def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
        self._inner = self.Inner(self.df)

     class Inner:
         def __init__(self, parent_df):
            self.parent_df = parent_df
```

Also see [Is it good practice to nest classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376127/is-it-a-good-practice-to-nest-classes)

Comment: Alright, so pretty much like the second link in my original post. Guess it cannot be avoided then. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
class Outer:

    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    class Inner(Outer):
        pass
```

`Inner` will now inherit `Outer`'s properties and methods

Comment: With this indentation you'll get `NameError: name 'Outer' is not defined`

Comment: Thanks for your response. This was what I was avoiding as indicated in my comment to @BeChillerToo's comment. But if there is no inherent way of doing this, I'd have to rely on it. Thanks!

Comment: @JackGoodall Following your indentation edit, this brings up an error `'Outer' is not defined` as @Matthias was saying in his comment. It works when treated as separated classes rather than nested classes. Either way thanks!