# Python Nesting Inner Classes - Object Programming

Tags: python, class, object, inner-classes

I would like to understand Python classes and objects.

I am trying and struggling to get the output results from inner-class, `Features`.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def first_name(self, first_name ):
        self.first_name = first_name
        return self.first_name

    def middle_name(self, middle_name):
        self.middle_name = middle_name

    def last_name(self, last_name):
        self.last_name = last_name
        return self.last_name

    class Features:
        def __init__(self):
            pass
        def color(self, color):
            self.color = color
            return self.color

x = Person()
print(x.last_name('Jimmy'))

print(x.Features.color('Brown'))
```

Instead I get this error:

> TypeError: Person.Features.color() missing 1 required positional argument: 'color'

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Don't give properties and methods the same name. Use `self._color` to signify that you're referring to a private member, and not the method again.

Comment: The4 code in your question doesn't produce any error. And why do you want to define a class inside of a class?

Comment: x = Person()
print(x.last_name('Jimmy'))

print(x.Features.color('Brown'))  , This is what produces the error

Comment: Don't add code to comments, edit your question.  Also, defining an internal class doesn't create the object. You still need to initialise it in init.

Comment: @MatBailie how do I edit?

Comment: @Motchello why do you think `x.Features.color('Brown')` *should* work? Why is `class Features` nested inside `class Person`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376127/what-are-the-consequences-of-nesting-classes

Comment: Nesting classes like this is of no use.

You have oto define a `Features` class at module level, and add an instance of it to your `Person` class in its `__init__` method.

Frameworks do sometimes use nested classes, but that is for the namespace, not for using those as "classes".

Comment: So there is no any other-way, or slight correction of displaying the input argument?

Comment: @VelterZi, But if i have to redefine it again, is that not the same as just having a separate class?

Comment: @jsbueno seeing that I still have to redefine another variable instance of the inner-class Features, I suppose you might be right then.

Comment: @Motchello the classes are separate. Nesting them doesn't change anything really, and just makes accessing the inner class needlessly difficult. It isn't clear what you expected the nesting to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner class is another class definition, just like the outer one.

```py
a_person = Person()
a_feature = Person.Features()
```

For using it, you need to define it.

```
x = Person()
print(x.last_name('Jimmy'))
y = x.Features() # Or just Person.Features()
print(y.color('Brown'))
```

And the reason for the error:

```
missing 1 required positional argument
```

It's because you're trying to call the `color()` function without initializing the Features class. This means that the `self` argument, which would refer to the initialized class that doesn't exist now, is not passed down to the `color` function.

So it's giving you the error because it takes your `"Brown"` as the `self` parameter and so nothing is given to the `color` parameter; hence the:

```
Person.Features.color() missing 1 required positional argument: 'color'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not personally nest classes like this, but if you want to do that for some reason, this is a first step forward. The key here is that as part of the `__init__()` of Person, we `__init__()` their Features.

```py
class Person:
    class Features:
        def __init__(self, color=None):
            self.color = color

    def __init__(self, first, middle, last):
        self.first_name = first
        self.middle_name = middle
        self.last_name = last
        self.features = Person.Features()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.last_name}, {self.first_name}\n\tHair Color: {self.features.color}"

person = Person("Jane", "Mary", "Doe")
person.first_name="Sara"
person.features.color = "Red"
print(person)
```

That should give you:

```
Doe, Sara
        Hair Color: Red
```

You also might explore [What's the pythonic way to use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters)